# Where to find processor failure notification in linux environment?

Tags: linux, cpu

I am currently working in **Linux** environment and I would like to know where **processor failure notifications** will be seen in Linux? and where these messages will be logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the message using **dmesg** command in linux environment. Where the kernal will log the related information

Answer (score 4):

In general Linux logs such failure in `/var/log/messages` .
Or install the package `mcelog` which logs these kind of errors under `/var/log/mcelog` (Machine Check Events log)

RHEL,CentOS,Fedora Linux

```
yum install mcelog
```

Debian,Ubuntu

```
apt-get update && apt-get install mcelog
```

Comment: Note that mcelog is not always running by default, and might even need to be installed manually first.

Comment: Also, the kernel itself only logs to **`dmesg`**. Whether it reaches `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/kernel.log`, `journalctl -f`, or other files, varies between distributions.

Comment: can you please help me with the exact log content that will be logged for processor failure, I have checked the log files but unable to retrieve the content @grawity

Comment: If occurs a processor failure, i am not sure whether booting occurs in a normal way.Will any issue be faced while booting my system.what abt the log content????????? @Jens Lindenberg

Comment: @anu have a look at http://mcelog.org/logfile.html section examples

Comment: @Jens mcelog says about hardware failure, fan failure...etc. But will anything be logged during a processor failure.

Comment: @Jens do u have any idea regarding a single core failure in multicore enviroment??????what if the core failed is the primary core???? How will we be notified????????

Comment: @anu look at the output from journalctl -k for dmesg messages from kernel about cpu

Comment: For a 2 core cpu normaly something like                                                 [    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 2 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.073319] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7600  @ 3.06GHz (fam: 06, model: 17, stepping: 0a)
[    0.086922] smpboot: Total of 2 processors activated (12206.00 BogoMIPS)                                                                                      shows up. In the case one core fails you see this  [    5.088430] smpboot: CPU1: Not responding
[    5.088440] smpboot: do_boot_cpu failed(1) to wakeup CPU#1

Comment: I didn't expect that I'd ever have to write "Do not nag me for free tech support via email and Google Hangouts" in my profile after merely commenting on an answer, but there you go. :|